# Tags power/power-management plus charger/charging

Tags: discussion, status-completed, synonym-request, tag-cleanup

Checking our tags for missing descriptions (tag-wiki), I came across above mentioned tags:

- [charging](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/charging) with the synonyms [charger](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/charger) and [battery-charging](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/battery-charging)
- [power-management](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/power-management) <del>(no synonym)</del> with the synonym [battery-manager](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/battery-manager)
- [power](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/power) (no synonym)

Questions tagged [power](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/power) are either belonging to [charging](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/charging) or [power-management](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/power-management). So my suggestion would be to check all questions tagged [power](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/power), and re-tag those to [charging](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/charging) which rather belong there (I volunteer doing this, if the overall task/concept is agreed on) . After that, converting the tag [power](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/power) into a synonym to [power-management](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/power-management).

I still miss the rep for some tasks involved (e.g. converting a tag into a synonym, or even propose it such) -- but as said, I'd volunteer for the re-tagging part.

While on it: [power-options](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/power-options) (3 questions altogether) should either be "dropped" (by re-tagging those 3 questions), or simply be made a synonym to [power-management](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/power-management) -- which is what those 3 questions relate to.

Opinions?

Comment: Sounds good, though "power-options" and plain "power" probably just need burninating, once their questions have been retagged. Anyone typing "power" into the tag box should get the right tags suggested straight away, and if there's no tag then there's less encouragement to use it!

Comment: Agreed :) Just let me know if there's anything I should do. Shall I retag those 3 (power-options->power-management)? Will the "empty tag" then be removed automatically (it finally will, but when?) and thus no longer pop-up in the tag box?

Comment: Well, I know "bump" is not a nice word -- but as it looks like we somehow agreed, but nothing happened: Might I ask how to proceed with those?

Comment: I just notice: The "power*" part already has an (also still open) request here: [Tag merge: power, power-management, power-options](http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/questions/1229/tag-merge-power-power-management-power-options)

Comment: Half a year is a long time, so some things have changed in the meantime; new questions tagged 'power-options' raise the question this tag might address the menu popping up on long-pressing the power button, so it might make sense (after cleanup and re-tagging).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So *most* of this already happened at some point (October of last year, it looks like?):

- [charging](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/charging) is the master for both "charger" and "battery-charging"
- [power-management](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/power-management) is the master for "battery-manager"

The only thing not really covered was the other `power-*` type tags, but there's another question specifically focusing on that anyway: [Tag merge: power, power-management](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1229/tag-merge-power-power-management)