# Tag merge: power, power-management

Tags: discussion, status-completed, synonym-request, tag-cleanup

Should we merge the tags [power](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/power) (× 62), [power-management](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/power-management) (×<del>14</del> 20 (merged with 'battery-manager'))? I'd suggest keeping the first tag, and making the second a synonym to it.

Many questions tagged [power](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/power) are dealing with power-management. However, there are also many dealing with powering on/off the device, which would speak for keeping them separated. In this case, we should at least re-tag the relevant questions. Note that the excerpt of the [power](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/power) tag currently reads:

> For questions about power-management, power on/off, and the like.

Just noticed, the [power-management](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/power-management) tag wiki excerpt reads:

> All about how to get the most out of your device's ressources, especially managing power consumption

Which would be quite similar to [battery-life](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/battery-life) (oops)...

Comment: As [agreed on in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8801617#8801617), I will ASAP check all questions tagged 'power' which are rather refer to 'power-management' and re-tag them accordingly. Then we can decide what to do with the left-overs :)

Comment: OK, that's done as well. So now what? 'power' -> 42, 'power-management' -> 30. Simply adjust the tag wikis? Still merge (and adjust tag wikis)?

Comment: Would it make sense to rename `power` to `power-on` and merge `power-management` into `battery-life` as a synonym?

Comment: According to their tag-wikis, that even looks like the perfect way. Half of the questions tagged `power-management` even tagged `battery-life` at the same time. I see no Q which could not go that way (2 might not be perfect matches, but well). So: Absolutely yes for that merge from me! As for `power`, that looks mixed (power adapter specs, power off, etc.). Maybe power-on + synonym power-off? But what about power-adapter-specs? Re-tag => charging? // I at least go and remove the "power management" from the 'power' tag wiki meanwhile :)

Comment: OK, re-tagged a couple of power-Qs to 'charging'. Still a few irregularities, but marginal. I'd say: Yes to both now -- power => power-on/power-off, power-management can be merged to 'battery-life' (alsore-tagged some exceptions). And then 'status-completed' here -- wonderful, thankx @MatthewRead :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we discussed, we now have [power-on](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/power-on) and a new synonym for [battery-life](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/battery-life) :)

Comment: Thanks a lot, Matthew! What do you think about the "power-off" synonym and, more important, something like "power-supply" as synonym for 'charging', so auto-completion leads there?

Comment: @Izzy I'm not sure `power-off` is needed, but I don't think it will hurt so I will add it.  Not sure about `power-supply` ... I can see reasonable questions being asked about it that don't necessarily fit in with other classes of `charging` questions.

Comment: So where do you see power-supply questions fitting into? I was at a loss there while re-tagging (luckily the Qs I had were at least related to charging, like "can I use any power supply to charge my X"; but what about one I remember asking for "permanent power supply w/o battery", which definitly is *not* charging-related?

Comment: @Izzy If there's enough of them, their own tag.

Comment: OK, if you say so :) I just couldn't find any. But the generic "hardware" tag could do :) So thanx, accepting your answer, done :)

Comment: @Izzy I *hate* that tag :P